# Filtering dataframe based on conditional minimum/nadir values (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

For a given time series dataset with values corresponding to IDs:

I want to A, locate the minimum values of each grouped IDs, then B, conditionally check if that grouped list has subsequent values that are 2 greater than the minimum value (`minPlus2`), for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'value'[8,5,3,2,1,2,3,13,8,5,3,2,1]})
```

patient ID 1  fits the criteria of having a value (`df.value[6]`) 2 greater than the minimum/nadir value of 1 (`df.value[4]`). Patient ID 2 doesn't match the criteria as there are no numbers after its nadir value (`df.value[12]`).

so far I have been able to find the nadir values using:

```
dfMin = df.loc[df.groupby('ID')['value'].idxmin()]
```

I don't know of a way of checking B, if there are subsequent values after the mins that are 2 greater than the identified mins and if so returning those in a separate variable.

The ideal output is those values that are 2 greater than the minimum values of each set of groups. The index placement of these values is not significant as long as it is subsequent to the minimum value.

```
dfMin = 
id       1
value    1

dfMinPlus2 = 
id       1
value    3
```

Comment: You question is super unclear, please try to rephrase it

Comment: hi @TomRon my apologies for the lack of clarity. I have updated the question, kindly let me know which parts need further clarification. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**:

Thanks to the comment, I was able to clarify the problem and have come up with a solution.

To test the first requirement (value >= minimum value for id + 2), you need a series that holds the minimum value for the id of each record. If you group the dataframe by id and call the `value` series's `min()` method, that is the result. You will need to drop the index from that series (the `groupby()` method messes with index).

To satisfy the second requirement (value occurs in a record after the min value's record), simply use the `idxmin()` method as you have identified above. This will return a series of the index of the minimum value for the id of each record.

Then you can compare the dataframe's `value` series with the first series and the dataframe's `index` with the second series with a bitwise `&` operator in between and achieve the desired result (I think).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'value': [8,5,3,2,1,2,3,13,8,5,3,2,1]})

min_value = df.groupby('id')['value'].min()[df['id']]

min_value.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

min_index = df.groupby('id')['value'].idxmin()[df['id']]

df['condition'] = (df['value'] >= min_value + 2) & (df.index > min_index)
```

The result is a new series in the dataframe that tells whether or not the given record satisfies the desired conditions.

**OLD ANSWER:**

The question is still a little unclear (what is your ideal output?), but I came up with this code which tests each id's grouped values to see if there is a value present that is two indexes after the minimum value's index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'value': [8,5,3,2,1,2,3,13,8,5,3,2,1]})

def test_id(id):
    '''Returns true if there is a value present two indexes after the minimum value, false otherwise'''
    min_index = df.groupby('id').value.idxmin()[id]
    indices = df.groupby('id').indices[id]
    return (min_index + 2) in indices
```

With this, `test_id(1) == True`, `test_id(2) == False`.

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry for the unclarity. The ideal output are values that are 2 greater than the minimum values of each set of groups. The index placement of these values is not significant as long as it is subsequent to the minimum value. I am trying to index by values compared to the mins not by their placement.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your response, it was very helpful. However, this method returns false positives as it compares the entire list as opposed to just those values subsequently AFTER the min.

Comment: Got it, sorry for the confusion. The answer has been updated. I believe this should satisfy your requirements?

Comment: yes! works perfectly. thank you for the neat & simple solution.

Comment: Hi Sam, since you were so helpful with this question do you mind taking a look at this question which is a bit more advance ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543616/finding-conditional-local-minima-values-in-time-series-python

Answer (score 0):

You can try out transform, which is like groupby but returns the data with the original indexes after aggregating

```
df[df['value'] == df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(np.min) +2]
```

Comment: This is a neat function, but how do I further segment those values that are strictly AFTER the min value?

I recieved this : 

        id,  value,  condition
    2,    1,      3,       True
    6,    1,      3,       True
    10,   2,      3,       True

however, index 2 should be false because its before the min(index 4). index 10 should be false because it too is before the min(index 12).